# How do I add a reference in fsharpi that has a version and public key in Mono

Tags: f#, mono, fsi

The following #r command will execute fine on Windows

`#r "System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"`

On Osx with Mono 3.0.6 it cant find the file even though the file is in the search path.

Im guessing that this might be to do with delay signing in Mono, can anyone confirm this or know what the best work arounds are?

Comment: In windows it binds to the following: --> Referenced 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.dll'

Comment: What does `#r "System, Version=4.0.0.0"` do?

Comment: Thats exactly the same, doesn't find any reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently The `#r` reference with a fully qualified name is not supported in Mono.

There are areas in the [F# code](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/build.fs#L4084) that check for the presence of Mono and revert to file only loading of references.  This was due to limitations in xbuild support at the time of writing.

Now that xbuild is more mature hopefully this can be addressed.

*Thanks to Don Syme for pointing me to this area*